# select value from date before 9am everyday

Tags: oracle, datetime, calculation

I have a table that tracks mileage of 10 vehicles every hour every day in a oracle database. For example:

```
Car | Mileage| Timestamp
Honda | 23.4| 11-Jan-17 08.00.00.000000 AM
Honda | 22| 11-Jan-17 09.00.00.000000 AM
Honda | 21.3 | 11-Jan-17 10.00.00.000000 AM
Honda | 24.4| 11-Jan-17 11.00.00.000000 AM
Honda | 23.2| 12-Jan-17 08.00.00.000000 AM
Honda | 25| 12-Jan-17 09.00.00.000000 AM
Honda | 26| 12-Jan-17 10.00.00.000000 AM
```

I dont understand how I can write a query to run this everyday for last 1 years worth of data and select mileage for every car before 9am everyday

Comment: OK, a few things. You probably have more than one `car`, so why are all of them the same in your sample data? Then - does "before 9am" include 9am itself, or is it excluded? And what does "before 9am" mean anyway - between midnight and 9am? or 9am one day until 9am the next day?

Comment: yes there are multiple cars and 9am is excluded. I want to retrieve the mileage for date that is closest to 9am but between midnight and 9am

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean mileage later than midnight and prior to 09:00 then the following will do the job and also cope with other car makes.

```
WITH base_data AS
(SELECT car, mileage, read_date , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY car,TRUNC(READ_DATE) ORDER BY read_date DESC) as ranking
   FROM   wg_test
  WHERE  EXTRACT (HOUR FROM read_date) BETWEEN 0 AND 8
    AND read_date > SYSDATE - 365)
SELECT car, mileage, read_date
  FROM base_data
 WHERE  ranking = 1
```

Comment: Yes I want the mileage for the timestamp closest to 9am. I believe this query will extract all hours between midnight and 9am? My date column is in timestamp datatype

Comment: You say that 9am is excluded . . . so your test data can only show 1 row per day.

Comment: Yes I want to exclude 9am and want to show 1 record per day (the record that is closest to 9am)